# Not update jquery dom after append row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, dom

Through Ajax, I add to the page partial view in ASP.NET MVC.

```
else if ($prodFound.length > 2) {
                var $findProduct = $("#ProductsFound").val();
                var $link = "@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home")?product=";
                $('#shoppingListResult').load($link + "" + encodeURIComponent($findProduct));
```

$prodFound - this is value for adding.
Next, using jquery I add the following row. They added, but have the same name - name=[1].Quantity. Apparently DOM is not updated. The event belongs to the button #addProduct. 
This is the code for this method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '#addProduct', function (e) {
                addProduct();
            });
        });

        function addProduct() {
            var $table = $('#containerOCR'),
                $row = $table.find('#trOCR').clone(true),
                $prodFound = $('#ProductsFound').val();
            if ($table.length > 0 && $row.length != 0 && $prodFound.length > 2) {
                var $countRow = $table.length;
                var $rowNew = $row.first();
                //The value of the hidden field (is transferred as model)
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".GoodName"]').val($prodFound).attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].GoodName');
                //Displayed value
                $rowNew.find('#GoodName').text($prodFound);
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Quantity"]').val('0').attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Quantity');
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Price"]').val('0').attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Price');
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Date"]').attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Date');

                $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Quantity"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Quantity');
                $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Price"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Price');
                $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Date"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Date');

                $('#containerOCR tr:last').after($rowNew);
            }
            else if ($prodFound.length > 2) {
                var $findProduct = $("#ProductsFound").val();
                var $link = "@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home")?product=";
                $('#shoppingListResult').load($link + "" + encodeURIComponent($findProduct));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't really debug this without a [mcve]. Namely, you need to show what that action you're pointing to returns. Also, that script must be within a file that gets rendered via Razor (i.e., not a static .js file) or that @Url.Action() is not going to work.

Comment: Ajax fulfills as it should. Most likely problems in cloning, it seems I have copied a reference to a row, and i need a new object.

Comment: Maybe you could use jQuery .clone() method?

https://api.jquery.com/clone/